# Parsefloat with 2 decimals without losing function to do equations (not as string)

Tags: javascript

I've seen multiple topics regarding this question, but none seem to answer it.

I want to round a number to two decimals, but without losing the function to use it in equations. So it shouldn't be transformed to a string. This DOES NOT work for what I want: `parseFloat("50").toFixed(2)`

Does anyone know how to parseFloat with 2 decimals as a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just parse it back to a float.

```
parseFloat(Number(1.2345).toFixed(2)); //1.23
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript a number cannot have trailing zeros. 2.5 is a correct but 2.50 is not, this is why `toFixed` returns a string, not a number.

The best way to handle what you need is to store the number as a number and let it round out to whatever it needs. Only when showing the number on the screen should you do the `toFixed(2)` method to transforms it into a string.

```js
// js
const price = 7.999999

const reducedPrice = price * 0.8

const finalReductionPrice = reducedPrice / 2.666666

// html
<p>price {price.toFixed(2)</p>
<p>reducedPrice {reducedPrice.toFixed(2)</p>
<p>finalReductionPrice {finalReductionPrice.toFixed(2)</p>
```